# swift 3 reordering collectionView cell with core data

Tags: core-data, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

please help to do reordering in collection view, here is my code, does not work. I don't understand why

```
 var dataEntity = [Chart]() // my Core data
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    let source = dataEntity[sourceIndexPath.row]
    let destination = dataEntity[destinationIndexPath.row]
    dataEntity[sourceIndexPath.row] = destination
    dataEntity[destinationIndexPath.row] = source



        do {

            try context.save()

            print("save")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }



}
```